# Failure of a single number duing bulk SMS sending

Tags: sms

I am sending SMS to my clients via my application. Suppose if am sending a message to 100 mobile numbers, one of it happens to be a non existing mob number. How can I skip that number alone and send rest of them? I use a try catch block in the method when the message can't be delivered, it goes to catch and the rest of the numbers can't be sent. Any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: Show us some code. What platform? What provider? What language?

Comment: Sounds like you are writing a sms spam bot :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you are using something like this:

```
try {
    foreach(string number in numbers) {
        // send sms here
    }
}
catch()
{
    // do error handling here
}
```

Do it like this:

```
foreach(string number in numbers) {
    try {
        // send sms here
    }
    catch() { 
        // do error handling here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the mobile number before sending the message and if it is a mobile number youu just send.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a "look up" on the number, usually the [Aggregator](http://www.openmarket.com/) you use will have this service